# HTML tag for including hidden "text/html" content when x-frame-options:DENY

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

Is there any HTML tag I can use for requesting content of the `"text/html"` mime type, when all the response from the server contains x-frame-options:DENY?

I tried to do `<script src="path" type="text/html"></script>`, but the browser just ignores this tag.

The reason I'm trying to do that, is for getting the cookie from a server that returns only those kind of response.

Thanks.

Comment: You should use ajax for this.

Comment: What would you use the cookie for?

Comment: I cant use ajax because it is cross domain. Basically I need the cookie so I can perform CORS ajax calls later during the session. If I don't have the cookie im getting a redirect response, that doesn't have CORS headers.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. iframe, object and embed won't work because the responses contain "x-frame-options:DENY". I will edit the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

If `.html` `document` is served with CORS, you can use `<link>` element with `import` set at `rel` attribute.

```
<link id="html" rel="import" href="/path/to/file.html" type="text/html">
<script>
  document.querySelector("#html").onload = function() {
    console.log(this.import)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good answer, but it doesn't help me. When I do that I have the same problem as in the ajax calls; I'm being redirected to a server that doesn't return CORS headers because I don't have the cookie yet.

Comment: @AMT You could try using `YQL`.

Answer (score 0):

After trying almost all the HTML tags that exist, I've found one that worked for me. Surprisingly, it was the `<img>` tag.

Unlike the `<script>` tag, when fetching `text/html` with the `<img>` tag, no error is thrown (in dev console). Because I care only about getting the cookie, I can make this image hidden and everything works.